# Redirect to a external website , while getting any error on request

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to redirect to a failure url whenever any error occured while calling the controller . We dont want to see "Whitelabel Error Page" page . Please advice

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ts")
public class MainController implements ErrorController {


@Value("${failure.location}")
private String failureLocation;



@GetMapping("/{dirtid}/{carrierid}/{userid}")
public String getTemp() throws IOException {
// code 
}
```

Trying to redirect to a failure location

```
@RequestMapping(value = ERRORPATH, produces = "application/json")
public void error(HttpServletResponse response) {

    response.setHeader("Location", failureLocation);

}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return Constants.ERRORPATH;
}
}
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/, e.g. see [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should @ControllerAdvice for managing all kind of Exception. It treated as Global Exception handler. From there you can set the response status code etc.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(SQLException.class)
    public String handleSQLException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){
        logger.info("SQLException Occured:: URL="+request.getRequestURL());
        return "database_error";
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="IOException occured")
    @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
    public void handleIOException(){
        logger.error("IOException handler executed");
        //returning 404 error code
    }
}
```